# Reinstall GRUB for multiple OS

Tags: 14.04, grub2, windows-7, boot-repair

On my PC, I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Mageia distribution. Recently I installed Windows 7 on a partition but could not get my grub back. I tried boot-repair but in vain and mageia is getting loaded.

How can I repair by grub to view list of OS'es to choose to boot from.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to use Boot-Repair's advanced mode and choose Ubuntu and drive to install grub2's boot loader into. If not post link to the summary report that Boot-Repair can run.

Comment: It would be a good idea to post your boot repair log. Do you know the location of your grub installation? you may be able to mount that from Mageia and run grub update from there. If nothing works it also may be a good idea to use Windows disk to run repair windows. That will get you into windows 7 and lock everything else out. From there you can use boot repair so as to get the boot menu back

Answer (score 0):

Can you access your windows 7?

if you can, and you don't insist on repairing grub. You can use Easy BCD. Download the free version of program and install it on your windows 7. It can automatically find your GRUB2 options and add them to windows boot menu. It's very easy, you can figure it out. I've used it many times for similar situations. Works like a charm.

Comment: I cannot access my windows 7. Currently it is booting into Mageia without prompting for anything. I am not able to see Windows 7 nor Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I'm not suggesting it's the best way to do it but how about using windows installation disk to repair its boot? Although it doesn't fix your problem, it's reliable and it will enable you to access the windows and then do the rest